# What is default timeout for http request in Nancy FX?

Tags: .net, http, request, timeout, nancy

> What is the default value of timeout?

Can I change request timeout in Nancy FX?

Answer (score 1):

Nancy doesn't have a default timeout itself. It depends on the host you are running Nancy on.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2736